# How can I download the Android support libraries as a whole directory in my device? (Android device, not pc)

Tags: download, android-source

How can I download the Android support libraries as a whole directory in my device? (Android device, not pc)

I want to download it, for a purpose. I am not to use SDK or android studio, just Google Chrome.

Comment: You must specify your purpose of downloading these libraries on your device. These are libraries and are linked to applications on compile time, so it is not common/reasonable to want them on a directory on your device.

Comment: Bro actually. I am a sketchware user where you can't add libraries by naming dependencies. So I have to manually add them via a directory. That's the reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android support libraries ( now AndroidX ) are open source, and can be downloaded here : 
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev